# Sending message to existing form class

Tags: c#

hope someone can help me with this issue. I have been trying different things for a while and I have tried a few solutions that I found on here and other site to no avail but as I am a novice, I think I have probably missed something. Here goes.

I am writing an application and I want to add in the ability for users to send messages to each other and have them pop on the screen. This is fine, the message is delivered and the form pops but if the user sends another message, it creates a new instance of the class. It doesn't appear to be finding the open form. I have tried a few things to search through open forms:

```
    //Receive message is started by the OpenListeningSocket function 
    //ProcessingThread = new Thread(() => ReceiveMessage());

    private void ReceiveMessage()   
    {
        Socket newSocket = tempServerSocket;
        NetworkStream netStream = new NetworkStream(newSocket);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(netStream);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(netStream);
        String message;
        String sender; 
        try
        {
            do
            {
                message = br.ReadString();
                sender = br.ReadString();

            } while (br.PeekChar() > 0);
            /*
            //FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
            for(int i = 0; i <= Application.OpenForms.Count; i++)
            //foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if(Application.OpenForms[i].Text == sender)
                //if (frm is Message)
                {
                    Message liveMessage = (Message)Application.OpenForms[i];
                    if (liveMessage.Text == sender)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("liveMessage Message detected");
                        liveMessage.lbMain.Items.Add(sender + ": " + message);
                        liveMessage.cbUsers.Text = sender;
                        liveMessage.cbUsers.Enabled = false;
                        liveMessage.TopMost = true;
                        liveMessage.TopMost = false;
                        liveMessage.ShowDialog();
                        //liveMessage.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
                else if(Application.OpenForms[i] is Message)
                {
                    newMsg = new Message();
                    newMsg.Text = sender;
                    newMsg.userName = userName;
                    newMsg.cbUsers.Text = sender;
                    newMsg.cbUsers.Enabled = false;
                    newMsg.lbMain.Items.Add(sender + ": " + message);
                    //msgList.Add(newMsg);
                    newMsg.ShowDialog();
                }

            }

            */

            if (msgList.Count < 1)
            {
                Message newMsg = new Message();
                newMsg.Text = sender;
                newMsg.userName = userName;
                newMsg.cbUsers.Text = sender;
                newMsg.cbUsers.Enabled = false;
                newMsg.lbMain.Items.Add(sender + ": " + message);
                msgList.Add(newMsg);

                newMsg.Visible = true;

            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Message msg in msgList)
                {
                if (msg.Text == sender)
                    {
                        //Message msg = (Message)frm;
                        msg.lbMain.Items.Add(sender + ": " + message);
                        msg.cbUsers.Text = sender;
                        msg.cbUsers.Enabled = false;
                        newMsg.Visible = true;
                        //msg.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
     }
```

I have tried looking through all the open forms in the Form Collection and if the form is of the Message class, cast it to Message. I couldn't get this to work. I tried adding all new Message instances to a Generic List of type Message and then iterating through them but this didn't work, maybe being disposed by the ProcessingThread?

I have tried looking at some instant messaging application examples but I haven't come across how they send the new message to the existing form.

If anyone has any helpful hints or could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Cameron.

Comment: Message form if you need only one window to be opened. Keep a global variable. Instantiate it when you receive the first message and keep adding to the same message window. To show or hide, just change the visible settings of the form.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I would like the end user to have the ability to receive many messages just like in an Instant Messaging application such as Yahoo Messenger.

Comment: Then you may need to create a global list of all message forms created for individual users